# Set height of progressbar as per the text on it

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I want my progress bar to overlay text on it. The text, if long, should dynamically change the height of the progressbar so the full text will be visible.

How do I dynamically set the height of progressbar as per the length of the text?

Here's my html code..

```
<ul>
 <li class="progress" style="position: relative;">
  <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 60%; float: left;"></div>
  <div style="position: absolute;">         
    <a href="#"> My TEXT </a>
  </div>            
 </li>
</ul>
```

This is how the text looks like now.

[image]

Comment: This is how the text looks like now..
http://i.imgur.com/NZKmVrW.png

Comment: Code in fiddle will be useful.

Comment: The relevant css is not present. A div would usually adapt it's height to its content unless you tell it not to...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `position: absolute` on the text, which removes it from the flow, and makes the parent ignore it.

To fix this you could apply `position: absolute` to the progress bar, and then position it behind the text using z-index.

The code would look something like this:

```
<ul>
 <li class="progress" style="position: relative;">
  <div class="progress-bar" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom:  0; width: 60%; z-index: 0;"></div>
  <div style="position: relative; z-index: 1;">         
    <a href="#"> My TEXT </a>
  </div>            
 </li>
</ul>
```